# Identifying submitted page url for Contact form 7

Tags: contact-form, contact-form-7

I am currently using a single form through **Contact Form 7** for visitors to download pdf files on my website. Once they fill the form and clicking the submission button, the related pdf file will be downloading.

However, I want to export the information about visitors whoever downloaded the pdf file for a specific page. I downloaded the report from Contact Form DB but it does not show any link or page name that visitors submitted the form. I believe there is a way to identify or fixing this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extention](https://www.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/).

Use the shortcode below in your form to retrieve the current page URL:

```
[dynamictext yourfieldname "CF7_URL"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather not add an extra plugin, it's also possible to record which page a user submitted a CF7 contact form from using a [hidden field](https://contactform7.com/hidden-field/) and a little bit of inline JavaScript.

Here is an example of what such a CF7 template might look like:

```
<label> Message [textarea message] </label>

[hidden page-url]

<script>
document.querySelectorAll('.wpcf7 input[name="page-url"]').forEach(function(element) {
  element.value = window.location.href;
});
</script>

[submit "Submit"]
```

Basically, the embedded script here is finding all instances of CF7 inputs with the specified name ("page-url" in this case) and changing their [value properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value) to the page's current URL, which is determined using the [window location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href).